# identify groups with few observations in paneldata models (stata)

Tags: stata, panel-data

How can I identify groups with few observations in panel-data models?

I estimated using xtlogit several random effects models. On average I have 26 obs per group but some groups only record 1 observation. I want to identify them and exclude them from the models... any suggestion how?
My panel data is set using: `xtset countrycode year`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's suppose your magic number for a big enough panel is 7 and that you fit a first model.

```
   bysort countrycode : egen n_used = total(e(sample))
```

then gives you a count of how many observations were available and can be used, after which your criterion for a later model is `if n_used >= 7`

You could just go

```
bysort countrycode : gen n_available = _N
```

regardless of a model fit.

The differences are two-fold:

1. That last statement would disregard any missing values in the variables used in a model fit.
2. If you also used `if` and/or `in` to restrict model fit to particular subsets of observations, then `e(sample)` knows about that, but the  last statement does not.